# Qt error: 'QMediaPlaylist' file not found

Tags: debugging, qt5, qtmultimedia

I'm using Qt 5.15.10
I have added QtMultimedia and Qt_USE_MULTIMEDIAWIDGETS but it still has bug like this and I tried to search on the internet and fix that but it still wasn't solved.
So What can I do for solving this problem? Thanks all of you guys!

Answer (score 0):

Please check:

1. In your build system (CMake or qmake) you need to add Multimedia.

   1. In qmake:  `QT += multimedia`
   2. In CMakeLists.txt:

```
find_package(Qt6 REQUIRED COMPONENTS MultimediaWidgets)
// ...
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC
    Qt::MultimediaWidgets
)
```

2. Some of libraries must be added during installation process. In Qt6 Multimedia must be selected, check if you have the library. If not run QtMaintenanceTool and add library to your current version.

---

EDIT: In question you mentioned about Qt5, but in topic of the question there are no information about Qt5, so people having the same  problem with `QMediaPlaylist`' in Qt6 are reading your question.
In QT6 the [class was removed](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtmultimedia-changes-qt6.html). ALternative code:

```
    QMediaPlayer player_;
    QAudioOutput* audioOutput = new QAudioOutput(&player_);
    player_.setAudioOutput(audioOutput);
    player_.setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile("pathToFile/music.mp3"));
    audioOutput->setVolume(50);
    player_.play();
```